# Using SED to cut after 7th character of each line

Tags: text-processing, sed

Just trying to cut any characters after the 7th on each line of a text.

I initially tried this:

```
sed 's/(.{7}).*/\1/' TestText.txt
```

But got this response:

```
sed: 1: "s/(.{7}).*/\1/": \1 not defined in the RE
```

Then tried this:

```
$ sed 's/./&#/7' TestText.txt 
Ballbou#nce
Latllma#tattjsdf
dsfase,#d,
adfadfj#jen
asdfjov#moeo
$ sed -e 's/#.*//' TestText.txt 
Ballbounce
Latllmatattjsdf
dsfase,d,
adfadfjjen
asdfjovmoeo
```

But all it did was remove the `#`. I just want to remove any character after the 7th character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sed` with `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/(.{7}).*/\1/' file
```

Or escape the brackets:

```
sed 's/\(.\{7\}\).*/\1/' file
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use `grep` (`-E` activates extended regular expressions, `-o` prints only the matching pattern):

```
grep -oE '^.{7}' file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,7)}' file
```

And of course `cut` is just made for this kind of job:

```
cut -c1-7 file
```

Comment: You should use `-E` instead of `-r`. `-E` is supported by GNU and some BSDs and is going to be in the next POSIX spec. (and `-r` doesn't make sense)

Comment: Note that on GNU systems, `cut -c` doesn't support multi-byte characters, using `sed` is a work around.

Comment: `grep -oE '^.{7}'` (a GNUism) will remove the lines that have fewer than 7 characters.

Comment: I used the `cut` method and that worked. Cheers!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Regarding -E and -r are you talking about sed ?

Comment: @User112638726, yes. In GNU `sed` `-E` as an alias for `-r` was added [in 2006](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=3a8e165a), but only documented [in 2013](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/commit/?id=8b65e079)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, -E doesn't work in my GNU sed. `GNU sed version 4.1.5` from 2003 :(